# How to set OnClick android cardview example with gridlayout

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have an Android project to create grid layout items that can be clicked on. I'm confused about where to set the On Click Listener and what the code looks like. here is my Adapter code program :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <FruitViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List< FruitsData > mFruitList;

    MyAdapter(Context mContext, List< FruitsData > mFruitList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mFruitList = mFruitList;
    }

    @Override
    public FruitViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_row, parent, false);
        return new FruitViewHolder(mView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final FruitViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mImage.setImageResource(mFruitList.get(position).getFruitImage());
        holder.mTitle.setText(mFruitList.get(position).getFruitName());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFruitList.size();
    }
}

class FruitViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView mImage;
    TextView mTitle;

    FruitViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);


    }
}
```

Thanks for your attention..

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have to do the following steps:

1. Define a ClickListener interface

   ```
   public interface OnItemClickListener {
     void onItemClick(FruitsData item);
   }
   ```
2. Pass your ClickListener to the constructor of your adapter

   ```
   MyAdapter(Context mContext, List<FruitsData > mFruitList, OnItemClickListener listener) {
       this.mContext = mContext;
       this.mFruitList = mFruitList;
       this.listener = listener;
    }
   ```
3. Then create a setter for the listener

   ```
   public void setListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
     this.listener=listener;
   }

   //and ease your constructor
   ```
4. Set an onClickListener to your viewHolder and call your listener

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final FruitViewHolder holder, int position) {
       final FruitsData item = mFruitList.get(position);
       holder.mImage.setImageResource(item .getFruitImage());
       holder.mTitle.setText(item getFruitName());
       holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override public void onClick(View v) {
               listener.onItemClick(item);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: then do I need to add some code to the MainActivity.java?

Comment: You have to modify the constructor of your adapter and define an interface. You can define the interface seperate or as an inner interface of your adapter (i would prefer the second approach, but its up to you)